# Model-view-Controller c# bring the gui and the model together

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, model-view-controller

I am making the game of minesweeper and I wrote the game all on the gui in c#. I want to now work on the model-view aspect of things and I need help bringing the gui together with the model.
Meaning:

I made a call called MinesweeperModel which in it will contain a 10 x 10 grid[,] of values. If the grid has a bomb the value will be -1 if not it will be 0. In the model view all of the methods are written there, like NewGame(), GameOver(), SetUp(), GameLogicChecker()(this checks if there are any bombs and assigns the square a value to how many bombs it is near) etc. However in the gui aspect of things I have a similar grid of buttons[,] which are also 10X10. What I am trying to do is when I click on a button that coordinate will correspond to a coordinate in the model grid, and therefore the method created in the model grid can work on the buttons as well. But I am not exactly sure how to bring it together.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could go through and add button click events to each button by double clicking it in the gui editor.  Then having it call the GameLogicChecker() function inside of it.  Maybe you could give a little bit more information I'm not quite sure what your asking for.